# Given $a>0$, $b> 0$, $a+b<10$, how to prove that $ab <25$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

As titled,

Given $a>0$, $b> 0$, $a+b<10$, how to prove that $ab <25$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the AM-GM inequality $\dfrac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab}$ for all $a,b \ge 0$.

If you don't know that, you can do this more directly as follows:

$$4ab = (a^2+2ab+b^2)-(a^2-2ab+b^2) = (a+b)^2-(a-b)^2 \le (a+b)^2 < 10^2 = 100,$$

so $ab < 25$.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Say $ab \geq25$. Since $$10> a+b\geq 2\sqrt{ab} \geq 10$$ we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$ab<a(10-a)=25-(a-5)^2\le25$

Answer (score 0):

a*b = [(a+b)-b]*b < (10-b)*b, since a+b <10.  $\max_{0 < b \leq 10} (10-b)*b = 25$ for b = 5.

That is a*b < (10-b)*b < 25 for 0 < b < 10.